# Remove a given item from a boost::intrusive::list

Tags: c++, boost

I have a pointer to an object that is guaranteed to be in a boost::intrusive::list. Given that pointer/object, can I remove it from the list ?

The following illustrates what I'm trying to do:

```
#include <boost/intrusive/list.hpp>

struct MyStruct : public boost::intrusive::list_base_hook<>  {
    int i;
    MyStruct(const MyStruct &) = delete;
    MyStruct& operator= (const MyStruct &) = delete;
    MyStruct(int val) : i(val) {}
};

void test()
{
    boost::intrusive::list<MyStruct> l;
    MyStruct a(1);

    l.push_back(a);

    MyStruct* p = &a;
    //At this point I have a pointer to an item that is in the list,
    //Given this pointer, is there any way I can remove that item from the list ? 
}
```

Comment: _"This fails, as it seems remove() will remove the item by value"_ You gave it a value. `*p` is not a pointer. It is the thing being pointed to. It's less confusing when you write your declarations like this: `MyStruct* p = &a;`

Comment: I just want to remove the node I linked into the intrusive list, do you have a way of doing so ? As the item is not copied into the list, it surely should be possible to remove it given the original node that was added to the list.

Comment: Looks like it takes a predicate which you can create trivially http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/intrusive/erasing_and_disposing.html

Comment: That appears to be an O(n) operation, which is undesirable when I already have the item to remove right at hand. If the answer is that it's not really possible, I'm fine with that too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove it like this:

```
l.erase(boost::intrusive::list<MyStruct>::s_iterator_to(*p));
```

Notice that it is not destroyed, it only gets removed from list.

Also if you've used hook with auto unlink option then you could've removed it by simply:

```
p->unlink();
```